# How do I set the default tab for tab bar controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to Swift, and about a 5 out of 10 on the **Objective-C** knowledge scale..

I created a basic three tab Swift application. Each tab has an associated swift class file, e.g. **FirstViewController.swift** , **SecondViewController.swift**, **ThirdViewController.swift**.

When I select the third tab, I now open the application preference settings using a `viewDidAppear` function override in **ThirdViewController.swift**, e.g.:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // open app preference s
    if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Though, prior to opening the preferences, I would like to set the active tab back to the first tab. How is this done elegantly in Swift.

The following does not work:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

As the `UIViewController` of the **ThirdViewController** class does not have a `tabBarController`.

Brian.

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }     I have tried using the same approach and it works for me

Comment: Thanks Omkar. Can you explain why this works. Without the optional question mark, the compiler states 'UITabController? does not have a member named selectedIndex'. Though at runtime, it appears one is present. New to swift and optionals. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Correction: This somewhat works. The first time the app settings are opened, the application user preferences are not listed. The second and further times I select the tab and open the app settings, all settings are now listed - though system preferences are present. This appears to be an app setting synchronization issue. I posted a separate question regarding app settings sync at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470391/how-do-i-synchronize-app-preferences-in-swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User Omkar responded above with the correct answer. I can successfully switch the first tab using the following viewDidAppear in ThirdViewController.swft

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {         
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0     
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I followed @Paolo Sangregorio way The code to do it as follows

in appdelegate find `applicationDidBecomeActive` function and add this lines

```
let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Use viewWillAppear (instead of) viewDidAppear to prevent a screen flicker


var freshLaunch = true
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if freshLaunch == true {
        freshLaunch = false
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want him to come without delay. Yo can use in viewDidLoad()

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set Default tab
    self.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tab bar application you should have the tabbarcontroller variable in your appdelegate.
You can set the current tab by setting the selectedIndex on that variable, from the appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Tab bar item

**Swift 3** 
 @IBOutlet weak var Tabbar: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
...
...
...
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![newIndex]

}