# How do I synchronize app preferences in Swift?

Tags: ios, appsettings

Previously, in an Objective-C application I needed to synchronize my iOS app preferences at startup  in the app delegate. This allowed proper preferences at startup. I used the following code (note the link to the original posting):

```
# https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-12/application-preferences
+ (void)initialize {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings"
                                                               ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle
                                                                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"]];

    NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
    NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];

    [defaults registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Is someone aware of an equivalent in Swift, or alternately - can you walk me through how to convert the above code to Swift.

__

I fixed ZAZ's code. The equivalent of the Objective-C class method (preceded with +) is the Swift Type Method which is identified with the 'class' keyword preceding the 'func override' keywords. I confirmed initialize() is called properly for the appDelegate with the below code.

Though, upon a fresh load of my app to my iPhone, and launching the Settings, the Apple "ALLOW xxx To ACCESS" settings are present, though my "xxx SETTINGS" are missing. If I hit the back arrow on the Settings, then click my app settings once again - my app settings are now present and remain available for subsequent launches.

I deleted the Apple Numbers app from my phone, then reloaded and launched Settings. All settings are present for the Numbers app on initial launch. So there is some form of initial load, and/or caching issue remaining. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
class override func initialize() {
    if let settingsBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "bundle") {
      let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: settingsBundle.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Root.plist"))
      let preferences = settings?.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers") as NSArray
      let defaultsToRegister = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: preferences.count)

      let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
      defaults.registerDefaults(defaultsToRegister)
      defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it not just be `defaults.synchronize()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code, please give it a try, hope this time it will do the trick

```
func initialize() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let settingsBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Root", ofType: "plist")
    let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: settingsBundle!)

    let preferences = settings?.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers") as NSArray

    let defaultsToRegister = NSMutableDictionary(capacity: preferences.count)

    defaults.registerDefaults(defaultsToRegister)

    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: How does this even relate to the question? I see nothing alike in there.

Comment: Your example did not compile correctly. See my above listing for a grammatically correct version which as yet does not display the user app preferences on first load.

Comment: Thank you ZAZ, let me try this out and get back to you. The original Obj-C method begins with +, which means it is a class method as opposed to an instance method with - preceding. is Swift Initialize a class or instance method equivalent? I suspect when this segment is executed is paramount in producing the correct results. Will get back to you within a few hours.

Comment: plz mark this as correct answer if it is for futture users who search for this syntax

Comment: ZAZ, updated your image and it states it is undergoing peer review. will mark it correct when possible.

Comment: Showing error in Xcode 7.3 as

 "Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]' "

any idea?